# Update datatable jquery

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am using the dataTable plugin from http://www.datatables.net and I want to remove what the plugin does and apply it again because I have a function which adds a new row to the table (I am adding it like this: `htmlContent="<tr><td></td>..</tr>", $(myTableBody).append(htmlContent)`) and if a apply to my table again the plugin it doubles the search field, the pagination field and so on and I want only the old table to have an update, can someone help me? In the updateTablePlugin I want to update the table.

```
$(".tableBody").each(function() {
                            var tableName = $(this).attr("name");
                            if (tableName == type) {
                                $(this).empty();
                                var contentHTML = "";
                                for ( var i = 0; i < resourcesJSON.length; i++) {
                                    if (type == resourcesJSON[i].requesttype) {
                                        contentHTML += "<tr>";
                                        contentHTML += "<td>" + resourcesJSON[i].batchid + "</td>";
                                        contentHTML += "<td>" + resourcesJSON[i].responderservice + "</td>";
                                        contentHTML += "<td>" + resourcesJSON[i].requestorservice + "</td>";
                                        contentHTML += "<td>" + resourcesJSON[i].requesttype + "</td>";
                                        contentHTML += "<td>" + resourcesJSON[i].priority + "</td>";
                                        contentHTML += "<td>" + resourcesJSON[i].holdstatus + "</td>";
                                        contentHTML += "<td>" + resourcesJSON[i].sequence + "</td>";
                                        contentHTML += "<td>" + resourcesJSON[i].queuename + "</td></tr>";
                                    }
                                }
                                $(this).append(contentHTML);
                                updateTablePlugin(tableName);
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: what dataTable plugin are you using?

Comment: Can you provide any source code? A link to jsfidldle are very welcome either.